# how to add overlay item in my current location in this code

Tags: android

Here is my code !! i want to add overlay item in my current 
location !! but  seems a problem i cant can any one check what i have 
to add to my code to just put overlay item appear in my current location Please Check it up .

```
package tryanabtry.opa; 
import java.util.List; 
import android.app.PendingIntent; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.content.res.Resources; 
import android.graphics.Bitmap; 
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory; 
import android.graphics.Canvas; 
import android.graphics.Point; 
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable; 
import android.location.Location; 
import android.location.LocationListener; 
import android.location.LocationManager; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.os.Handler; 
import android.util.Log; 
import android.widget.TextView; 
import android.widget.Toast; 
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint; 
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity; 
import com.google.android.maps.MapController; 
import com.google.android.maps.MapView; 
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay; 
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem; 
public class tryanabtry extends MapActivity 
{
    private MapView mapView; 
    private MapController mc; 
    int error=100; 
    GeoPoint p, p2, p3, p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12,p13; 
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays; 
    Drawable drawable, drawable2 , drawable3, 
    drawable4,drawable6,drawable7,drawable8,drawable9,drawable10,drawable11,drawable12,drawable13,drawable5; 
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay, itemizedOverlay2 , 
        itemizedOverlay3, 
        itemizedOverlay4,itemizedOverlay5,itemizedOverlay6,itemizedOverlay7,itemizedOverlay8,itemizedOverlay9,itemizedOverlay10,itemizedOverlay11,itemizedOver lay12,itemizedOverlay13; 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        try{ 
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            setContentView(R.layout.main); 
            /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */ 
            LocationManager mlocManager = 
                (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
            LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener(); 
            mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 
                0, mlocListener); 
            mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView); 

            mapView.setStreetView(true); 
            mapView.setSatellite(true); 
            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
            mc = mapView.getController(); 

            mc.setZoom(12); 
            addOverLays(); 
        }
        catch(Exception e){ 
            Log.d("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",e.getMessage()); 
        }
    }

    public void addOverLays(){ 
        String [] coordinates = 
            {"31.216487288475037","29.932637214660645" ,"30.084123015403748", 
            "51.5002" , "-0.1262","31.337149143218994"}; 
        double lat = 29.98739718380868,lat2 
            =29.98763859272003,lat3=29.987574219703674,lat4=29.98718498160553; 
        double log = 31.442527770886084, log2 = 
            31.44235074520111,log3=31.44225418567575,log4=31.442527770996094; 
        p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (log * 1E6)); 
        p2 = new GeoPoint( (int) (lat2 * 1e6), (int) (log2 * 1e6)); 
        p3=new GeoPoint( (int) (lat3 * 1e6), (int) (log3 * 1e6)); 
        p4=new GeoPoint( (int) (lat4 * 1e6), (int) (log4 * 1e6)); 

        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays(); 
        drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.vitblue); 
        drawable2 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballon); 
        drawable3 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blackaaaaa); 
        drawable4 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.vitblue); 
        itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this); 
        itemizedOverlay2 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable2,this); 
        itemizedOverlay3 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable3,this); 
        itemizedOverlay4 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable4,this); 
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "Cairo", " over1"); 
        OverlayItem over2 = new OverlayItem(p2, "ulm", "over2"); 
        OverlayItem over3 = new OverlayItem(p3, "offff", "over3"); 
        OverlayItem over4 = new OverlayItem(p4, "offff", "over4"); 
        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem); 
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay); 
        itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(over2); 
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay2); 
        itemizedOverlay3.addOverlay(over3); 
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay3); 
        itemizedOverlay4.addOverlay(over4); 
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay4); 
        mc.setZoom(17); 
    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 
    {
        @Override 
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 
        {
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(    (int) (loc.getLatitude() * 
                1E6), 
                (int) (loc.getLongitude() * 1E6)); 
///////////////////////////////////MY NEW EDIT \\\\\\\\\\\\\
            mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            drawable11 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.vitblue);
            itemizedOverlay11= new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable11,this);
            OverlayItem over11 = new OverlayItem(point, "offff", "over5");
            itemizedOverlay11.addOverlay(over11);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay11);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// /////////The constructor HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable, tryanabtry.MyLocationListener) is undefined ////// error 
            String Text = "My current location is: " + 
                "Latitud ="+ loc.getLatitude() + 
                "Longitud =" + loc.getLongitude(); 
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), 
            Text, 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            mc.animateTo(point); 
        }

        private Resources getResources() { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            return null; 
        } 

        private void DoubletoString(double latitude) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        } 

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
        {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), 
                "Gps Disabled", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show(); 
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
        {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), 
                "Gps Enabled", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle 
                extras) 
        {
        }

        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() { 
            return false; 
        }
    }/* End of Class MyLocationListener */ 

    @Override 
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        return false; 
    } 
}
/* End of UseGps Activity*/
```

My HelloOverlay classs

```
package tryanabtry.opa; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import tryanabtry.opa.tryanabtry.MyLocationListener; 
import android.app.AlertDialog; 
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder; 
import android.content.res.Resources; 
import android.graphics.Bitmap; 
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory; 
import android.graphics.Canvas; 
import android.graphics.Color; 
import android.graphics.Paint; 
import android.graphics.Path; 
import android.graphics.Point; 
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable; 
import android.util.Log; 
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint; 
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay; 
import com.google.android.maps.MapView; 
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay; 
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem; 
import com.google.android.maps.Projection; 
public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> 
{
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new 
    ArrayList<OverlayItem>(); 
    tryanabtry m = new tryanabtry(); 
    public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, tryanabtry n) { 
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker)); 
        m = n; 
    }
    @Override 
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) { 
        return mOverlays.get(i); 
    }
    @Override 
    public int size() { 
        return mOverlays.size(); 
    }
    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) { 
        mOverlays.add(overlay); 
        populate(); 
    }
    // ////////// 
    public void draw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
            boolean shadow) { 
        class MapOverlay extends Overlay { 
            private GeoPoint pointToDraw; 
            public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) { 
                pointToDraw = point; 
            } 
            public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() { 
                return pointToDraw; 
            } 
            @Override 
            public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, 
                    long when) { 
                super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow); 
                // convert point to pixels 
                Point screenPts = new Point(); 
                mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, screenPts); 
                // add marker 
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
                    R.drawable.ballon); 
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 24,     null)
                return true; 
            } 
            private Resources getResources() { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                return null; 
            } 
        }
        GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (29.987574219703674 * 1E6), 
            (int) (31.44225418567575 * 1E6)); 
        GeoPoint p2 = new GeoPoint((int) ( 29.98763859272003 * 1E6), 
            (int) (31.44235074520111 * 1E6)); 
        GeoPoint p3 = new GeoPoint((int) (29.98718498160553* 1E6), 
            (int) (31.442527770996094 * 1E6)); 
        GeoPoint p4= new GeoPoint((int) (29.98739718380868 * 1E6), 
            (int) (31.442527770886084 * 1E6)); 
        // Let's assume you've assigned values to these two GeoPoints now. 
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection(); 
        Point startingPoint = projection.toPixels(p, null); 
        Point startingPoint1 = projection.toPixels(p, null); 
        Point startingPoint2= projection.toPixels(p2, null); 
        Point endingPoint = projection.toPixels(p2, null); 
        Point endingPoint1 = projection.toPixels(p3, null); 
        Point endingPoint2= projection.toPixels(p4, null); 
        // Create the path containing the line between the two points. 
        Path path = new Path(); 
        path.moveTo(startingPoint.x, startingPoint.y); 
        path.lineTo(endingPoint.x, endingPoint.y); 
        Path path1 = new Path(); 
        path1.moveTo(startingPoint1.x, startingPoint1.y); 
        path1.lineTo(endingPoint1.x, endingPoint1.y); 
        Path path2 = new Path(); 
        path2.moveTo(startingPoint2.x, startingPoint2.y); 
        path2.lineTo(endingPoint2.x, endingPoint2.y); 

        Paint paint = new Paint(); 
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
        paint.setColor(Color.RED); 
        Paint paint1 = new Paint(); 
        paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
        paint1.setColor(Color.GREEN); 
        Paint paint2 = new Paint(); 
        paint2.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
        paint2.setColor(Color.YELLOW); 
        // Draw the path! 
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow); 
        // el super de 3shnnn to addd koloooo overlay w path 
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint); 
        canvas.drawPath(path1, paint1); 
        canvas.drawPath(path2, paint2); 
    } 
    @Override 
    public boolean onTap(int i) { 
        try { 
            String s = mOverlays.get(0).getSnippet(); 
            String[] infos = s.split(","); 
            Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(m); 
            builder.setTitle("Information about: " + infos[0]); 
            builder.setIcon(m.getResources().getDrawable( 
                m.getResources().getIdentifier(mOverlays.get(0).getTitle(), 
                "drawable", "net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps"))); 
            builder.setMessage("age: " + infos[1] + "\njob: " + infos[2] 
                + "\ninstitute: " + infos[3]); 
            builder.setPositiveButton("ok", null); 
            builder.show(); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { 
            Log.d("3'lt", "lihh ya wdi3", e); 
        } 
        return true; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this piece of code at your onLocationChanged

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    overlayList = mapView.getOverlays();
    MyLocationOverlay object = new MyLocationOverlay(yourclass.this, mapView);
    overlayList.add(myLocation); 
    myLocation.enableMyLocation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but the reason you are getting the error:

> The constructor HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable, tryanabtry.MyLocationListener) is undefined

is because of your use of `this` when calling the constructor of `HelloItemizedOverlay`.  In this context, `this` refers to the instance of `MyLocationListener` which the code is within, and not an instance of the class `tryanabtry`.

Replace this line:

```
itemizedOverlay11= new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable11,this);
```

with this:

```
itemizedOverlay11= new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable11,tryanabtry.this);
```

Please also note that by convention Java classes should start with a capital letter, so `Tryanabtry` instead of `tryanabtry`.