# error in adding overlay in current location

Tags: android

[how to add overlay item in my current location in this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986211/how-to-add-overlay-item-in-my-current-location-in-this-code) 
this is my code  of adding over lay item in my current location but i get this error

```
enter code here
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

{ @Override

 public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

           {





GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(    (int) (loc.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
        (int) (loc.getLongitude() * 1E6));
 mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
drawable11 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.vitblue);
itemizedOverlay11= new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable11,this);
OverlayItem over11 = new OverlayItem(point, "offff", "over5");


itemizedOverlay11.addOverlay(over11);
```

//The constructor HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable, tryanabtry.MyLocationListener) is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the class HelloItemizedOverlay in your project and you are calling the constructor correctly....

Comment: sure i'm having helloitemized overlay  but the question how can i call the constructor correctly its always give error

Comment: after adding the constructer it force close when i run the program

Comment: i was once asked the samething before, well i think the second parameter in the constructor is context, try your code by giving null here....